# How do I extract or read a csv file from 7z file using Python?

Tags: python, csv, 7zip

I uploaded a zip file to my EC2 Linux notebook, and extracted it, the extracted files were in 7z format rather than csv. So is there a way to extract from the zip file in a csv format or convert/read 7z into csv?

I have already tried the existing solutions given for similar questions, but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Unsure whether the `zip` module can process 7z files. My advice is to use 7zip to extract the csv file, and only then process it with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution -

This will install the 7zip tool :

```
 sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

This will extract the .7z file in a .csv file :

```
7za x <filename.tar.7z>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract zip files in 7z format using the [py7zlib module](https://github.com/fancycode/pylzma/blob/master/py7zlib.py) from pylzma. Alternatively, you can extract it using something like [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/).